# Show that each of the coefficients of a complex power series are real

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Suppose that $g(z) = \sum c_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $R > 0$
>   and that $g(\frac{1}{m})$ is real for all $m > \frac{1}{R}$. Show that each
>   $c_n$ is real.

I know that if $R>0$ then $ \frac{1}{m} >  \lim_{n \to \infty}\left | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right | > 0$

Also if $g(\frac{1}{m})$ is real then $\sum \frac{c_n}{m^n} \in \mathbb{R}$

Maybe I could try and show that $\frac{1}{m^n}$ is real.

I'm not really sure where to go from here, any help getting me in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Limit of g(1/m) for m to infinity gives the result for c_0. The case of  c_1 follows from the derivative at zero, which you can write as the limit of m  times [g(1/m) - c_0)] for m to infinity. The general result can be obtained using induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$
h(z) = \sum \overline{c_n} z^n 
$$
has the same radius of convergence, and $h(\overline z) = \overline{g(z)}$ for $|z| < R$.

In particular, since both $\frac 1m$ and $g(\frac 1m)$ are real,
$$
 h(\frac 1m) = g(\frac 1m)
$$
for $m > \frac 1R$. It follows from the identity theorem that
$h(z) = g(z)$ for all $|z| < R$, and therefore
$\overline{c_n} = c_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: This A is  just too long! LOL. +1